# Java File Reading Problem

Tags: java

I am trying to read my highscore.txt file so that I can show it on my game's highscores menu. 
The content of my highscore.txt is SCORE and NAME.  Example:

```
   150 John
   100 Charice
   10 May
```

So I write the following code to read the file in a text area but the file cannot be read. My code is as follows:

```
public HighScores(JFrame owner) {
        super(owner, true);
        initComponents();
        setSize(500, 500);
        setLocation(300, 120);
        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.getHSBColor(204, 204, 255));

        File fIn = new File("highscores.txt");
        if (!fIn.exists()) {
            jTextArea1.setText("No high scores recorded!");
        } else {
            ArrayList v = new ArrayList();
            try {
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fIn));
                String s = br.readLine();
                while (s != null) {
                    s = s.substring(2);
                    v.add(s);
                    s = br.readLine();
                }

                br.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Couldn't read high scores file");
            }

            // list to display high scores
            JList jlScores = new JList(v);  //there's a problem here. I don't know why
            jTextArea1.add(jlScores, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        }
    }
```

What am i doing wrong??? How can I make this work>. You're help would be highly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You might want to look at how you parse the lines of text from your file. `s = s.substring(2);` just drops the first two chars from the string. You might instead want to split the string on a space charater to obtain an array of tokens; in this case [0] will be the score and [1] will be the name.

Comment: @Qwerky  how can i do the splitting? thank you

Comment: Check the API docs for String at http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html there is a method called `split`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are reading the contents of the file into an `ArrayList v` which you are then doing nothing with after populating it.

Your code to display the scores is adding an empty `JList` to your `jTextArea1`. You likely want to fill the `JList` with the contents of `ArrayList v`.

Comment: But how can i do that? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to initialize JList with ArrayList object.

```
JList jlScores = new JList(v);
```

I think that could be the problem because there is no JList constructor with ArrayList, there is [one with Vector](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#JList%28java.util.Vector%29).

Answer (score 1):

```
JList jlScores = new JList(v);  //there's a problem here. I don't know why
```

There isn't a constructor that takes an arraylist, have a look at the constructors in the [javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html). Instead, convert the arraylist to an array and then use that in the constructor.

As to how to convert the arraylist to an array, I'll leave that as an exercise since this is homework, a bit of Googling should do the job no problem!

Answer (score 1):

As described in the [JList Tutorial](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), I'd recommend using a ListModel to populate the JList, as follows:

```
//create a model
DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

//now read your file and add each score to the model like this:
listModel.addElement(score);

//after you have read your file, set the model into the JList
JList list = new JList(listModel);
```